# Simple password verification

Tags: c++

> Im relatively new to coding, could use help adding a simple password >verification for this code. User should be prompted to put the password in >once they choose option 4, if wrong password they can try again or go back >to the start, if the right password they continue to option4

```
int bball::menu()

int menuChoice;
string passWord;

cout << "\n1. Print out all player statistics (Enter 1)" << endl;
cout << "2. Print out specific player's stats (Enter 2)" << endl;
cout << "3. Print specific teams stats (Enter 3)" << endl;
cout << "4. Update players data (Enter 4)" << endl;
cout << "5. Close menu (Enter 5)" << endl;
cout << "> ";
cin >> menuChoice;

while (menuChoice < 1 || menuChoice > 5 ) {
    cout << "Invalid choice";
    cout << "> ";
    cin >> menuChoice;
}

while (menuChoice = 5)
{
    cout << "Enter password: ";
    cin >> passWord;
    if (passWord == "Yaboi321")
        return menuChoice;
    else
        cout << "Wrong Password";
}

/*if (menuChoice = 5)
{
    cout << "Enter password: ";
    cin >> passWord;
    if (passWord == "Yaboi321")
        return menuChoice;
    else
        cout << "Wrong Password";
}
*/
return menuChoice;
```

}

Comment: `menuChoice = 5` is an assignment. Use == for comparison.

Comment: you compare with 5 (supposing = is ==) but in the question speak about _option 4_

Comment: You do not manage an input different than a number, you will definitively loop in that case, same in the EOF case both for the menu choice and the password

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You compare with 5 (supposing = is corrected to be == in the second *while*) but in the question it is about option 4

You do not manage an input different than a number, you will definitively loop in that case, same in the EOF case both for the menu choice and the password

A proposal :

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int menu()
{
  cout << "\n1. Print out all player statistics (Enter 1)" << endl;
  cout << "2. Print out specific player's stats (Enter 2)" << endl;
  cout << "3. Print specific teams stats (Enter 3)" << endl;
  cout << "4. Update players data (Enter 4)" << endl;
  cout << "5. Close menu (Enter 5)" << endl;

  int menuChoice;

  for (;;) {
    cout << "> ";
    if (!(cin >> menuChoice)) {
      // not a number, clear error then bypass word
      cin.clear();

      string dummy;

      if (!(cin >> dummy))
        // EOF
        return -1; // indicate an error

      menuChoice = -1;
    }

    if ((menuChoice < 1) || (menuChoice > 5))
      cout << "Invalid choice" << endl;
    else
      break;
  }

  if (menuChoice == 4) {
    string password;

    do {
      cout << "Enter password: ";
      if (!(cin >> password))
        // EOF
        return -1; // indicate an error
    } while (password != "Yaboi321");
  }

  return menuChoice;
}
```

Compilation and executions :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -pedantic -Wall -Wextra m.cpp
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out

1. Print out all player statistics (Enter 1)
2. Print out specific player's stats (Enter 2)
3. Print specific teams stats (Enter 3)
4. Update players data (Enter 4)
5. Close menu (Enter 5)
> 1
choice : 1
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out

1. Print out all player statistics (Enter 1)
2. Print out specific player's stats (Enter 2)
3. Print specific teams stats (Enter 3)
4. Update players data (Enter 4)
5. Close menu (Enter 5)
> a
Invalid choice
> 0
Invalid choice
> 4
Enter password: aze
Enter password: Yaboi321
choice : 4
```

It can be interesting to stop to ask for the password after a given number of consecutive invalid password read and return a number out of 1..5 to signal the case, else there is no way to stop the loop requiring password